# Redirect to a page that only show the contents of a component/page using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So when I click on a link (for example, the **Category 1** link), I want it to redirect me to a page where *only the contents of the* `Category1` *component are shown*, while the links (from Category 1 to 3) of the `SelectCategory` component are *hidden*. Instead, what happens is that the `SelectCategory` component is still showing while the content of the selected link are just put at the bottom of this component. And then I want to have a **Home** link in each category that takes me back to the homepage. (I attempted to do it below, but it fails.) Another problem I have is that whenever I click on a category link, I still need to refresh the page to show the contents of that category. Please help.

In summary, this is what I want:

1. Only show the contents of a selected link (or, component).
2. Have a **Home** link that takes me back to the homepage.
3. Show content of selected link without refreshing the page.

Here's my code:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import SelectCategory from './components/pages/categories/SelectCategory';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className='App'>
                <SelectCategory />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

SelectCategory.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Category1 from './Category1';
import Category2 from './Category2';
import Category3 from './Category3';
// import App from '../../../App';

const SelectCategory = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Select A Category</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/category1'>Category 1</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/category2'>Category 2</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/category3'>Category 3</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {/* <Link to='/'>Home</Link> */}
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/category1' component={Category1} />
                <Route exact path='/category2' component={Category2} />
                <Route exact path='/category3' component={Category3} />

                {/* An attempt to make a link redirect back to the homepage */}
                {/* <Route exact path='/' component={App} /> */}
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SelectCategory;
```

Category1.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Category1 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is Category 1</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Category1;
```

Category2.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Category2 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is Category 2</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Category2;
```

Category3.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Category3 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is Category 3</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Category3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

Typo in `SelectCategory` component, `BrowserRouter as Switch` should just be `Switch` since your router is running in `App`.

## Solution

- Fix the import.
- Conditionally render the category links

In `SelectCategory` you can render the category links into a route that exactly matches the "home" path (`"/"`) with the link back to home *outside* the route so it is always rendered. In order to redirect back to your "home" path you *actually* need a route rendering a "/" to be redirected to. Render an empty `Route` for the "/" path and finally render a `Redirect` component to "/" to handle any paths ***not*** handled by the `Switch`.

```
import { Link, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const SelectCategory = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <h1>Select A Category</h1>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <li>
            <Link to="/category1">Category 1</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/category2">Category 2</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/category3">Category 3</Link>
          </li>
        </Route>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/category1" component={Category1} />
        <Route path="/category2" component={Category2} />
        <Route path="/category3" component={Category3} />
        <Route path="/"></Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit redirect-to-a-page-that-only-show-the-contents-of-a-component-page-using-react-r]

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in SelectCategory.js.

```
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

to

```
import { Link, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```